# Find a value in a cell, select/activate another column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have trouble with Google Script.

I have a spreadsheet with unique values in a column. I need to find a value stored in a variable. Then activate that cell, move two columns to the right and copy the value of that cell or store the value as a variable.

Is this possible in Google Sheet?

One of the codes I tried:

```
    function slett() {
      var slett = 4; //define the value of the variable I'm searching for
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = ss.getSheetByName('Ark 1'); // name of spreadsheet
      var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
      for (var row in values) // look in each row
        if (values[row][1] == slett){  //if value in column B matches 'slett'....
                                         // activate the finding
                                         // move righet using offset
                                         // store value of that cell in a variable
           s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);  // delete the row
            break;                        // do not search for another instance of the 'slett'
    }
    };
```

I know how to move, but I can't figure out how to activate the cell with the 'slett'-value.

Comment: Can you share the code you have currently? Then we can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried 10-15 different codes and variations of them, but I'll just share one of them:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to search down column B for the value `slett` (4 in this case), and once you find it, store the value in column D of the same row. This is easy since you have already stored the values of the entire sheet:

```
if(values[row][1] == slett){
  var storeVariable = values[row][3];
  s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
  break;
}
```

You would only need to access the sheet again if you needed to get additional data from the sheet or write to it. For example, if you had only grabbed the values in column B instead of the entire data range, you would do

```
var storeVariable = s.getRange(row+1,4).getValue()
```

to get the value two columns over from where you found `slett`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I wish I could send you a big bouquet of flowers right now. :-) I spent ten hours yesterday trying to figure out this, and I was going down all the wrong paths. You made my day!

Comment: My pleasure. You can thank me by accepting the answer (please)!